# how to set header from a single file when reading multiple csv files with spark?

Tags: csv, pyspark, header

I have multi `.csv` file with same format. the name of them is like `file_#.csv`. the header of them is in first file (`file_1.csv`).
I read this file with `spark` whit this code:

```
spark.read.csv('*.csv', header=True)
```

When I show the result the header is not the header of first file, it is one of the data row.
How can we say to spark that header is in the which file?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in any generic elegant way using standard  spark.read apis.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file that has the header row, then you can generate the schema by reading the schema from the header file and then use the same schema to read all other files.

```
df1 = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True)
header = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=False).first()
df2 = spark.read.schema(df1.schema).csv(*.csv, header=False).filter(lambda line: line != header)
```

The code is also removing the header line from the data. You can improve upon the filter function if few fields can be used to distinguish the header from the data.